# jQuery Mobile best practice - panel button, back button, or both

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button, ipad-mini

I'm creating a mobile app targeted for iPad Mini.  I have a panel that slides out from the left with navigation menu.  I also have the need for a back button in the header.  What is the best practice for buttons in the header?  I need a back button at certain times in the flow of the application and I also need the button that opens the panel in the header too.

Thanks for your advice.

I forgot to mention the right side of header has a button that loads barcode scanner. So, I'm left with left side of header to compete for 2 buttons.

Comment: there's no best practice, header div can accommodate two buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hRP8a/ (jQM 1.4)

Comment: I forgot to mention the right side of header has a button that loads barcode scanner.  So, I'm left with left side of header to compete for 2 buttons.

Comment: you can something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n3y76/ you can also use footer to place buttons. _Please update your question with your comment_.

Comment: Thanks Omar.  That's what I needed.  Can you add your last comment as the answer so I can mark it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header can accommodate two buttons on right and left, `ui-btn-left` and `ui-btn-right` respectively.

However, you can place more than two buttons in header by using [*controlgroup*](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/controlgroups/) widget with `data-type="horizontal"` attribute.

```
<div data-role="header">
    <!-- right-hand button -->
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="bars">Bcode</a>

    <!-- if you don't want to use title,
    replace it with <span class="ui-title"></span> -->
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <!-- left-hand button -->
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-left">
        <a href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Panel</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="back">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n3y76/)** jQM <= 1.3
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/owx7u9w4/)** jQM >= 1.4